# Recovery mode stuck at Loading, please wait... Starting version

Tags: recovery-mode

I have this ubuntu VM and recently when I booted it virtual box gave me an error and shut down before it started

It happened the first time I booted my VM after installing docker and ran wsl --update, no idea if it is a coincidence

Since then, when I boot the VM I get stuck at recovering journal, after 10 minute nothing happen.

I am now trying with recovery mode and it seems to get stuck here
[image: please wait]